# Como compartir jMenuBar en varias ventanas de mi aplicación?

Tags: java, java-swing, jmenubar

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación java y **necesito compartir el mismo jMenuBar que tengo en mi jFrame de pantalla principal en un jDialog** que abro desde otro lado. 
En mi pantalla principal, creo el jMenuBar con java seing arrastrando los componentes en NetBeans.

Desde el jDialog hago:

```
nombreJDialog.setJMenuBar(pantallaPrincipal.getJMenuBar());
```

Cuando entro a mi jDialog se ve genial, pero **el problema es que después que cierro el jDialog y entro a mi pantalla principal ya no se ve el menú, es como si al usarlo desde la otra ventana ya dejara de poder usarlo en la principal.**

Si en cambio no abro el jDialog y solo abro la pantalla principal, entonces el menú se ve perfecto, el problema es si uso el menú en el jDialog antes.

Ideas para solucionarlo?

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré una posible solución: 
Es crear una clase que extiende de JMenuBar

```
public class LaBarra extends JMenuBar {

    private JMenu archivo;
    private JMenuItem salir;

    public LaBarra() {
        archivo = new JMenu("Archivo");
        salir = new JMenuItem("Salir");
        salir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                System.exit(0);//Solo para que cierre
            }
        });

        archivo.add(salir);
        add(archivo);
    }
}
```

Y cada que abre el JDialog se crea una nueva clase LaBarra

```
public class EjemploJmenuBar extends JFrame {

    private LaBarra laBarra;
    private JDialog ventana;
    private JButton lanzar;

    public EjemploJmenuBar() throws HeadlessException {
        setSize(500, 500);//Tamaño del JFrame
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3); 
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); //Centra la ventana
        setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

        laBarra = new LaBarra();

        lanzar = new JButton("Lanzar");
        lanzar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                ventana = new JDialog();
                ventana.setSize(300, 300);
                ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                ventana.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                LaBarra aux = new LaBarra();//Creamos una nueva
                ventana.add(aux, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                ventana.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        add(laBarra, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(lanzar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EjemploJmenuBar e = new EjemploJmenuBar();
    }

}
```

Sorry por no comentar todo el código, cualquier duda me avisas :D